# Why is the distance where electric field is zero different from the one where potential is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

I came across this exercise which says that in an xy plane there are two charges: q1 = q and q1 = -12q, and that q1 is at (0,0) on the plane and q2 at (0,9). I was asked to find the abscissa , which is said to be negative, of a point where the potential is zero.

As far as I know, when an electric field is zero at a point, then so is the potential (considering V = 0 at an infinite distance). Is this assertion wrong?
Assuming that I am correct, and since I know there will be a point at which potential is zero on the negative part of x axis, if I do find a point where electric field is zero, then I will know that potential is zero there. So , I found out at which distance the electric field created by both charges cancel out. I found it to be at a distance of 3.65 from charge 1, therefore, the point would be (-3.65,0). However, when I tried the more direct approach, which I thought was more correct even, I obtained a different result. I did  V = k*q1/|x| + k*q2/(|x|+q) and I got the result |x| = 0.81. So the abcissa is -0.81 vs -3.65. Which one is correct and why is the other wrong (or maybe both are wrong, I don't know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know, when an electric field is zero at a point, then so is the potential (considering V = 0 at an infinite distance). Is this assertion wrong?

In a multi-charge system, your assertion is wrong. First, the electric field is a vector sum with the individual contributions proportional to $r^{-2}$. The potential is a scaler sum with contributions proportional to $r^{-1}$. That means that the relationship of the potential to the field is one of a function to the slope (actually, its negative):
$$\text{slope of }r^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm d (r^{-1})}{\mathrm d r}= -r^{-2}.$$

So, if there is even a single case for which the slope is zero when a function is non-zero, the assertion is false. Consider a potential, $\phi$,
$$\phi = \frac{3}{x}-\frac{2}{x-5}\hspace{1 cm} 0\lt x \lt 5$$
The field would be
$$\vec{E}=\frac{3}{x^2}-\frac{2}{(x-5)^2}.$$
This field is zero at $x\simeq 2.75255$. The potential at that point is $\phi\simeq 1.9797 \ne 0$.

The "why" is basically that functions generally don't have  zero points where their slopes are zero, and the slopes usually aren't zero when the functions are. There may be special cases, but generally the two zeros (a function and its slope) don't coincide.